# How to click a button without name or ID?

Tags: javascript

How do I click on this button, without ID or Name:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn float_right btn" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;" value="Calcular" />
```

I've tryed:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("btn float_right btn").click()
```

and

```
document.getElementsByClassName("btn float_right btn")[0].click()
```

without sucess.

The console gives the error:

```
ERROR: Execution of script 'PP$1s' failed! document.getElementsByClassName(...).click is not a function
```

Comment: How about just `document.getElementsByClassName("float_right btn")[0].click()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to have the most specific selector, in order to avoid "clicking" on something else…

```
document.querySelector('input[value="Calcular"]').click();
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/420/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelector()` and target one specific element by classes. If you want more specific selector you can use something like this `input[type="submit"].btn.float_right`

```js
document
  .querySelector('.btn.float_right')
  .addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(this.value)
  })
```

```html
<input type="submit" class="btn float_right btn" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;" value="Calcular" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("btn float_right")[0].click();
```

```html
<input onclick='alert("You clicked!")' type="submit" class="btn float_right" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;" value="Calcular" />
```

Its's not an issue but class `btn` was repeated

Answer (score 0):

You can check by using this for get correct DOM.

```
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("btn float_right")[0]);
```

if there are other DOMs that have "classname" attribute name like it, you can not get coreect DOM.